# Using different layouts under a Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

In my app, I am using a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and I have various fragments with different items it the toolbar.

What is the correct way to implement that?
Should I use a different `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` for each fragment with it's child views, or should I use one main toolbar and hide/make visible elements? The latter seems messy and ungly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToolBar is basically just a simple ViewGroup so you can treat it this way. You can create a fragment holder in the ToolBar and then just replace it with any Fragment you want.

You can also put different views in it a hide/unhide them according to your logic. Either way is find, depends on your app needs.

Comment: Maybe I shell refine my question. How much of overhead is it to set a new toolbar as the actionbar for each fragment? Is it significant?

Comment: I don't believe it's a lot of an overhead. I do believe that you shouldn't set a new ToolBar for each fragment but just replace fragments in the same ToolBar.

Comment: Interesting approach. I will try!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also very elegant and simple.