# Android: Toolbar layout denpend on current fragment

Tags: android, toolbar

First at all, i have a main activity with a toolbar. This toolbar is used for all my fragments.

For each fragment i have some difference menu items. And the GUI for it quite complex.

I know there is the way that create menu for each fragment then use setHasOptionsMenu(true). But, when use the menu like that, it too hard to custom all the menu item as i want.

So, i created a toolbar with many layouts. Set it "gone" by default. When adding a fragment i going to set the corresponding layout visible and hide all other.

It solved my problem but i'm not satisfied with this solution. And i wonder if you have any better solution for it. Please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered to something similar to what you need... take a look over here [Using different layouts under a Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426883/using-different-layouts-under-a-toolbar/31427057#31427057)

Comment: So, you mean that in toolbar we create layout maybe. Then in each fragment we add/replace fragment_toolbar_view in to it. Right? :)

Comment: Here is a small question related to this. How can i center a view in toolbar when navigation button showed please?